# Launch emulator in REVERSE_PORTRAIT and REVERSE_LANDSCAPE mode i.e UPSIDE-DOWN mode

Tags: android

How to launch emulator in REVERSE_PORTRAIT and REVERSE_LANDSCAPE mode on linux?Ctrl+F11 and Ctrl+F12 is working only for NORMAL PORTRAIT and NORMAL LANDSCAPE mode.plz answer.even windows and mac people will need this.

Comment: as far as i know there is no support for REVERSE_PORTRAIT. Could you please clarify what do you mean by REVERSE_LANDSCAPE

Comment: portrait and landscape has two mode.one is normal and other is upside-down i.e reverse.

Answer (score 0):

Click 'Android virtual device manager' to eclipse.
then change the tab Device Definitions from Android Virtual Devices.
You will see a button 'New Device' click it.
Lastly, set Resolution (px) you want.

Additionally, I linked a blog you can see a guide pic just below.
http://blog.naver.com/oephm/100186089669

I hope it would help you..:D if you can't see this pic attached well, I would upload a better quality one.

Comment: thanks but i don't want resolution.i want how to rotate emulator upside-down.